# How do you say 'cooked pig small intestine filled with pig blood' in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, translation

In our culture, we usually serve cooked pig small intestine filled with pig blood in times of feast. Is there a single English word for this? In our language, it's *Sa-thithun*.

Comment: Which language is 'our' language?

Comment: It's Mizo language, less known and one of the tribal languages in Northeast part of India.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the UK it is called [Black pudding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_pudding#United_Kingdom_and_Ireland)

> While "blood sausage" in English is understood in the British Isles, the term is applied only to foreign usage (e.g. in the story [The Name-Day by Saki](http://www.eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/Name824.shtml)), or to similar blood-based sausages elsewhere in the world.

Comment: I haven't heard of Blood sausage, only Black pudding.

Comment: Both the cultural artifact and the term are rare in the US (except in the technical area of gastronomy), as exotic as 'spotted dick'. That is, if you use the term in the US, it would be rare to know what is referred to ('blood sausage' would be understood but you wouldn't know where to get it.)

Comment: @Tristan - Opposite for me here in the states.

Comment: T.E.D., that's strange.

Comment: In the US, it depends on where you live. _Blutwurst_ is often available in areas with European settlements or good Delicatessen, and _blood sausage_ is understood to be much the same thing. Like most local foods, this varies widely in terminology from place to place and from group to group. _Spotted dick,_ on the other hand, would be recognized as a funny name for something they eat in England, but nobody would know what it was.